# What are the differnet cudnn libraries

Tags: nvidia

I see many options on nvidia website, what are their differences?

cuDNN v7.0.5 Library for Linux

cuDNN v7.0.5 Library for Linux (Power8/Power9)

cuDNN v7.0.5 Runtime Library for Ubuntu16.04 (Deb)

cuDNN v7.0.5 Developer Library for Ubuntu16.04 (Deb)

cuDNN v7.0.5 Code Samples and User Guide for Ubuntu16.04 (Deb)

cuDNN v7.0.5 Runtime Library for Ubuntu14.04 (Deb)

cuDNN v7.0.5 Developer Library for Ubuntu14.04 (Deb)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48784645/9506872